# ¿Porque recibo distintos valores en una misma consulta mysqli php?

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

tengo un problema con una consulta mysqli de validación de login, el problema es que hay dos consultas de igual funcion pero obvio de distinta variable, una me arroja un resultado object con un array de valores, y la otra me retorna bool(false), el object array es el que sirve, porque valida el nombre de usuario pero el de la contraseña que arroja bool(false) no valida sino que el usuario aunque ingrese una contraseña incorrecta puede ir al area de perfil.

Mi codigo de php es este:

```
 <?php 

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$password = $_POST['passWord'];

include('connection.php');

$existUser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datausers WHERE Usuario = '".$usuario."'");

$existPass = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datausers WHERE Contraseña = '".$password"'");

var_dump($existUser);
var_dump($existPass);?>
```

Lo que me imprime el $existUser es:

> object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {"current field"}=> int(0)
>   ["field_count"]=> int(7)["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0)
>   ["type"]=> int(0)}

Lo que me imprime el $existPass = bool(false)

Comment: Y por qué no hacer todo en la misma consulta?

Comment: $existUser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datausers WHERE Usuario = '".$usuario."' AND Contraseña = '".$password."'");  --> Así?

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida. Cuando uses las funciones o métodos de PHP revisa lo que devuelven para saber cómo leer lo que traen.

En el caso de [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) el Manual dice que devuelve esto:

> Retorna `FALSE` en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT,
>   SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, `mysqli_query()` **retornará un
>   objeto `mysqli_result`**. Para otras consultas exitosas de
>   `mysqli_query()` retornará `TRUE`.

O sea, ante una consulta `SELECT` hay dos posibles resultados:

- `FALSE` si la consulta es errónea
- Un objeto `mysqli_result` en caso de éxito

De hecho el var_dump que muestras no son los resultados en sí de la consulta, sino el objeto `mysqli_result` que ha sido devuelto.

Ahora bien, ese objeto hay que leerlo, usando un método adecuado para ello.

Si lees la constitución de los [objetos `mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php), verás que tiene varios métodos para leer los datos que trae (son los métodos que empiezan por `fetch_`), pero tiene también una propiedad para conocer el número de filas que trajo el objeto. Para este caso, dado que se trata de saber si hay registros o no, puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `mysqli_num_rows` del objeto de resultado.

Si se tratase de obtener más datos, como un array de resultados, entonces convendría usar uno de los métodos `fetch_` de la clase.

Dicho todo esto, tu código puede escribirse así:

```
$usuario = (empty($_POST['usuario'])) ? NULL : $_POST['usuario'];
$password = (empty($_POST['passWord'])) ? NULL : $_POST['passWord'];
$totalFilas=0;
if ($usuario){
    include('connection.php');
    if ($conexion){
        if($existUser = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datausers WHERE Usuario = '".$usuario."'")){
            mysqli_store_result($conexion);
            $totalFilas = mysqli_num_rows($existUser);
        }else{
            echo "Consulta errónea: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
        }

    }else{
        echo "Conexión nula";
    }   
}else{
    echo "No se posteó un nombre de usuario";
}

//Hacer algo con $totalFilas
```

---

Si quieres verificar al mismo tiempo usuario y contraseña, puedes modificar la primera parte del código así:

```
if ($usuario && $password){
    include('connection.php');
    if ($conexion){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM datausers WHERE Usuario = '$usuario' AND Contraseña='$password'";
        if($existUser = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql){
         //todo el resto del código como más arriba
```

Comment: Gracias, iré a probar y ver en la documentacion esas funciones mysqli que implementastes que de verdad no conozco, en un momento te doy respuestas...

Comment: Ok me sirve validando el nombre del usuario , y lo digo porque al ver la variable con var_dumb al ingresar un nombre de usuario que yo se que en mi base de datos no existe, pues $totalFilas es igual a : int(1) . Pero si ingreso un nombre de usuario que si existe me dice : int(1).  Almenos sé que la función de mysqli_num_rows me determina el usuario.  Pero no entiendo que hace "mysqli_store_result($conexion)" por lo que entiendo en documentación es que transfiere un conjunto de resultados de la última consulta, pero igual sigo sin entender, disculpame, empezé a ver php en esta semana.

Comment: @Abdiel sí, es que no lo expliqué con mayor detalle. Generalmente, cuando se va a usar `mysqli_num_rows` antes hay que invocar a `mysqli_store_result` para que transfiera el conjunto de resultados, si no se hace, te muestra cero, porque los resultados no han sido metidos en el buffer, por eso en tu código el `var_dump` mostraba cero, porque los resultados no estaban en el buffer.

Comment: Ok, pues considerando que no puedo pretender entender todo este tema siendo tu que me lo expliques, y me conformo en este caso con lo que me has explicado, de hecho me validó el usuario, de aquí en adelante me leeré la documentación para enterder las consultas mysqli, considero que fuiste de ayuda por lo que a tu comentario lo marcaré como la solución, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y disculpa mi ignorancia, jej . Gracias.!

Comment: No será que los campos con tilde debieran ser escapados?

Comment: @amenadiel yo recomiendo no usar campos con tildes, caracteres especiales, `ñ`, etc. Esta vez se me escapó, aunque por lo general he visto que funciona aunque los campos tengan estos caracteres, pero como haya un problema con la codificación el código puede fallar.

Comment: Entre colegas, creo que es mejor resignarse a usar `agno` para almacenar un Año

Comment: @amenadiel yo he optado por nombrar las variables, nombres de campos, métodos... en inglés.

Comment: pero year es una función en mysql, de manera que igual terminas escapando campos